# codeigniter displaying error message on same page

Tags: php, codeigniter

another question again regarding codeigniter, here a few details:

view page:

```
<?php if (isset($error)){echo $error; } ?>
<form action="<?php echo site_url('mem_posting/post');>" method="post">  
<input type="text" name="fname">
some fields goes here...
</form>
```

controller page(mem_posting):

```
public function post_form()  
{
$this->load->view('header');  
$this->load->view(form_page);
}

public function post()  
{  
    $post_data=array(  
    'mem_id'=>$this->input->post('mem_id'),  
    //other inputs... 
    )
    $this->load->model('member_model');  
    if ($this->member_model->check_member($post_data)===true)  
    {  

   //row exist  
   // **i would like to load the same page but 
   // **with error message "like already exist".  

    }else{  
         $this->member_model->inset_member($post_data);
    }
}
```

model page:

```
public function insert_member($post_data=array())  
{  
 extract($post_data);
 $this->db->where('member_id', $member_id);
 $this->db->insert('membership', $post_data); 

}

public function check_member($post_data=array())  
{  
    extract($post_data);
    $this->db->select('mem_id');
    $this->db->where('mem_id', $mem_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('membership'); 

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return true;            
    }else{
         return false;  
    }
}
```

as you can see the view page contains the form, now what i would like to achieve is to echo an error like 'already exist' so i dont have to code another $this->load->view('post_form') inside the if statement.

thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean just sending a variable to the view?

```
$data['error'] = "error message";
$this->load->view('some/view', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well! you shoul run validation when your form is submited. So, imagine you have 2 fields submited. It would be like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mem_id', 'ID Member', 'required|trim|is_unique[yourtable.mem_id]|xss_clean');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()){
       // Do your cool stuff now because validation passed
    }else{
       // Whatever...validation fails, load your view.
    }
```

So in your view you shoul have somethin like this at top of the form:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

is_unique[yourtable.mem_id] will validate if the input is unique in your DB. So if is really unique, OK.

Comment: hi john, what i want to validate is if a row exist, if a row exist i would like to load the same page that contains the form but with error message,

Comment: Hi again! Sorry for my english, is not my native language, but if I did not misunderstood you...you submit a form, and validates if there is no row with that data, for example avoid having 2 rows with same username (for example). Is so, the code i posted will help you, is_unique[table.field] check that, and if there is a row with that data it will show error automatically. So if an user submit a new username, it will pass and do whatever you want, but...if the username exists....BOOM!